# Making a two dimensional array of checked check box values and the input text in the same row of an html table using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have an html table generated by php script using mysql data. It looks like this

```
<?php 

echo <table class='s_report'><tr><th>Request ID</th></th><th>Date of Reqst</th><th>Requst By</th><th> Remarks<br/>Fill All with first remark<input name='fill_all' type='checkbox' /> </th><th> Select All<input name='checkall' type='checkbox' /></th></tr>";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {
          $dateform=explode('-',$row['request_date']);
                    echo"<tr>";

  echo "<td>" .$row['request_id']. "</td>";

                      echo "<td>" . $dateform[2] ."-".$dateform[1]."-".$dateform[0]. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['user_name'] ."</td>";
  echo"<td><input name='rem_sec' type='text' value='NA'/></td>";      
         echo "<td text-align='centre'><input type='checkbox' class= 'app' id= 'app' name='app' value=".$row['request_id']."></td>";


  echo "</tr>";
          }

        // end of while
  echo "</table><br/></div>";

?>
```

I use following jquery to get value of all checked boxes.

```
var selected_ids = jQuery('.app:checked').map(function() { return jQuery(this).val();}).get();
```

This is woking and I get an array contaiong value of all checked boxes.

I wanted to get value of the input box (rem_sec) in respective rows of the table along with the check box value and get a two dimensional array like [[reqid1,remarks1],[reqid2,remarks2]]

If I make another array of all input box values it makes an array of all input boxes irrespective of the check box near to it is checked or not. Hence I need a sort of filtering. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think I would loop through each row

```
    var newArray = [];

    $( "table tr" ).each(function( index ) {

        var RowInputName= $("[name='rem_sec']");
        var RowCheckedValue= $(".app");

        var getRowInputName= $(this).find(RowInputName).val();
        var getRowCheckedValue= $(this).find(RowCheckedValue).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

        console.log( "getRowInputName: " + getRowInputName );
        console.log( "getRowCheckedValue: " + getRowCheckedValue);

        newArray[getRowInputName] = getRowCheckedValue;

    });
```